# Logging Shared Folder access in Windows environment

Tags: windows, logging, network-share

Is there a way to log users upon accessing shared folders in Windows Server? My goal is to write a program that sort of runs in the background monitoring the shared folders and logs user information whenever someone accesses the folder. How do I go about implementing it? What tools I should use to achieve this? Thanks in advance

I'm aware of the file auditing functionality provided by Windows. As Kyle Smith suggested this probably would become a nightmare to dig through tons of log entries to find relevant ones.It is also inefficient. So my question is how do I do this other than enabling "object access auditing". I need to implement this for both Windows Server 2003 & 2008

Comment: Think about it from the perspective of the OS on the server computer -- All it "sees" are requests by remote users to "open", "close", "read", "write", etc. It has no idea what application is running on the client, nor what that application *intends* by the operation it invokes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Windows logging by going to Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy and setting "Audit object access" to some value other than "No auditing." (Default)

Digging through these logging entries, on the other hand, will be a nightmare.

Comment: +1 - Nobody ever gets what they want out of object access auditing in Windows, because it's done at the filesystem API level. You get a lot of logs of "open", "close", etc, but not a clear log of events like "User xxx opened yyy file with Microsoft Word". Unfortunately, that's just the way the product works.

Answer (score 0):

You want to enable file auditing as per [this article on 2003.](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows2003/AdminTips/Security/AuditingAccesstoSensitiveData.html)  You don't say what version of Windows, but it's similar in 2008.